# backbone.js view uses old this.collection after second fetch()

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone view that manipulates elements in its collection (this.collection) when certain events fire. Occasionally the user may navigate so that the view is recreated with a new collection, and a new fetch() is called. When the events are fired after this second fetch() however, I run into problems because the event callbacks still see the old this.collection rather than the new one.

Is this because Javascript's functional scope binds the current namespace to the callback functions when they are first defined?  More importantly, how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by unbinding my old events (which had callbacks linked to the namespace where the old collection resided) and letting the backbone view rebind new events to the new namespace whenever I reset my collection.

Before each fetch() or reset():

```
if(app.galleryView !== undefined) {
    app.galleryView.undelegateEvents();
}
```